# ¿Porque pudeo inicializar un string con una inicializacion directa pero no con una referencia?

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

Porque pudeo inicializar un string con una inicializacion directa

```
string tentative("TENTATIVE");
string motAffiche = tentative;
```

pero no con una referencia

```
string tentative("TENTATIVE");
string motAffiche = tentative;
```

En efecto, me dice gedit que

> error: conversion from ‘std::__cxx11::string* {aka
>   std::__cxx11::basic_string*}’ to non-scalar type
>   ‘std::__cxx11::string {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string}’
>   requested

¿Está como si `motAffiche` y `tentative` tienen el mismo objeto, no ?

Comment: Revise su pregunta porque `string tentative("TENTATIVE");
string motAffiche = tentative;` en los ejemplos son iguales y compilan hasta en c++98, mejor ponga el codigo que esta usando y genera el error. Saludos

Comment: ¿No son tus códigos de ejemplo de *inicialización directa* e *inicialización por referencia* exactamente iguales? O___o¿

Comment: Ja ja ja los códigos son iguales y yo como medio minuto buscando la diferencia

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que en tu codigo original realmente te refieres a esto

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string tentative("TENTATIVE");
    string motAffiche = &tentative;

    return 0;
}
```

Efectivamente te devuelve un error porque estas intentando asignar la direccion del objeto string llamado tentative a una variable de tipo string lo cual es incompatible ya que la variable motAffiche deberia ser un apuntador a string.

Supongo que en tu pregunta te refieres a las referencias de c++ y no a simples apuntadores por lo cual una forma de lograr lo que quieres seria asi.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string tentative("TENTATIVE");
    string& motAffiche = tentative;

    cout<<tentative<<endl;
    cout<<motAffiche<<endl;

    cout<<&motAffiche<<endl;
    cout<<&tentative<<endl;



    return 0;
}
```

En el ejemplo los dos ultimos "cout" imprimen las direcciones de memoria de los objetos los cuales deberian ser iguales ya que en la segunda variable estamos haciendo referencia a la primera.